# Trigger event if DynamoDB record not updated in X seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have an usecase to trigger a recovery workflow if a client has not updated a DynamoDB record within say 5 seconds of it's creation.

Considered using DynamoDB TTL to trigger a lambda who would recreate the record after confirming if the state has changed, but not sure if TTL expiry deletes the item immediately and creates a DynamoDB stream notification o the deletion of expired records happens in the background at a later point of time. Also I want to retain the data record and cannot let it expire as there are other clients who could be querying the table for the same record in between the TTL expiry and lambda reinstating the record.

Is there any other approach I could take to set this up without removing/expiring the record?